# Can not deposit ether into a contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I tried to build a basic contract from some resources but failed to deposit the ether into this contract. 
Following is my code, is it correct that "msg.value" and "address(this).balance" be 0 at any time? 
If so, how can I send ether to another address?
If not so, how to deposit money in a correct method?

```
// can get balance
function getOnesBalance(address addr) public view returns (uint){
    return addr.balance;
}

// can get balance
function getMyBalance() public view returns (uint){
    return msg.sender.balance;
}

// 0
function getMyBalance2() public view returns (uint){
    return msg.value;
}
// 0
function getMyBalance3() public view returns (uint){
    return address(this).balance;
}

function deposit(uint _money) public payable {}

function getContractAddr() public view returns (address){
    return msg.sender;
}

function() payable {}
```

Comment: How are you transferring ether to the contract? Presumably, you're invoking either `deposit` or the fallback function. Are you doing that via code? If so, can you share that code? If not, can you tell us how you're transferring the ether?

Comment: `getContractAddr()` is wrong, it will return the address of the one who called the function..

Answer (score 2):

> is it correct that "msg.value" and "address(this).balance" be 0 at any time?

Yes, `msg.value` depends on each transaction. While address(this).balance will return the balance stored at the address of contract.

`msg.value` is number of wei sent with the transaction.

The contract given below will allow you to deposit ether to it, and then get the information who deposited how much:

```
contract MyContract {
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    function getOnesBalance(address addr) public view returns (uint){
        return balances[addr];
    }
    function getMyBalance() public view returns (uint){
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }
    function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function getContractAddress() public view returns (address){
        return address(this)
    }
    function deposit() public payable {balances[msg.sender]+=msg.value;}
    function() public payable {deposit();}
}
```

Corrections done are as follows:

- `deposit`: This function will be used to send ether to contract
- `function() public payable {deposit();}`: This is the fallback function which is executed whenever the contract receives ether.
- `balances[]`: You need to store the ether deposited by someone at a different variable. Here we are storing in the mapping named `balances`
- `getMyBalance`: This function will return the amount of ether deposited by the person who calls this function.
- `getContractAddress`: Contract address is retrieved by using `address(this)`.